Difference between getter and readonly property in an interface?
Let's assume two interfaces:
interface A {
    readonly x: number;
}

interface B {
    get x(): number;
}

Is there any difference between those interfaces if I can implement each of them using both a readonly property and a getter?
class ClassA implements A {
    // x = 1; <- same effect
    get x() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class ClassB implements B {
    // get x() { <- same effect
    //     return 1;
    // }
    x = 1;
}


There's no difference in the types; the get syntax for the interface was added in TS4.3. Of course at runtime a getter and a property are observably different but presumably you're not asking about that. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

There's no difference between a getter and readonly property you can use both interchangeably:
interface a{
  readonly x: number;
}
interface b{
  get x(): number
}

class A implements a{
  get x(){
    return Math.random();
  }
}

class B implements b{
  x = 1;
}

const av = new A;
console.log(av.x);
const bv = new B;
console.log(bv.x);

A typed getter is used when a broader setter is used for the assignment:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#separate-write-types-on-properties
So I would say - use a getter when you have a corresponding setter with different accepting types, otherwise use a readonly prop to avoid unnecessary complexity.
